# Handling webtables that load on scroll using selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

So here is a question that has and is always a blocker for me during automation using any tool. A solution using selenium would be what i need, however, solutions with any tool or API is most welcome.

Objective:- Read all rows from a webtable
Current solution:- get total rows using selenium ( here in selenium we try to get the total number of  tags to get the rows and then iterate them to get the values. This works well in a normal scenario.

The problem:- in a few applications we have tables, or other elements which are AJAX driven ( can be some other tech as well ) which due to the magnitude of data load it lazily or loads when we scroll to the last row of the table.

```
1. So when I read the table now it will have rows: 1 to 10
2. when i scrool down i get rows from 5 to 15 
3. This can go on..
```

Manually when we go to verify data is scroll down and let it load dynamically. Through automation, we are able to scroll, but this approach is very unstable.

Current solution:- Scroll down the table using clicks, scroll action using a mouse emulator but just a little bit and continue reading data, and continue till the entire table is read.

Issue:- This approach is 
                1. Too slow and inefficient.
                2. Unstable

What would be your solution to this problem. ( note:- reading from database works, but UI validation is not achieved )

Comment: separate tests where you test the display of un-paginated data in tables and test pagination in a different test with only a small amount of data to obtain past the first page. Implement retrying and decorate this test to be tried a few more times then normal before failure. Work on making the approach more stable, write some javascript to help the process along perhaps or investigate further built in options regarding scrolling in selenium.

Comment: because it is lazy loading you need to use a webdriverwait for each element you want to interact with.  If grabbing arrays of elements, you'll need to catch stale element exceptions and run the grab again.  (use a function that calls itself again when stale element is caught)  Assuming this is a finite table, you need some kind of detection of when the scrollbar stops scolling.  I think I saw that somewhere here...you use javascript to see if scrollheight changed... I'll see if I can dig up that script.

Comment: So I have tried to zoom out and that works for column of a webtable, but the rows are not all loaded, so I need to again scroll. Looks like I need to perform a partial test of only elements which are loaded. Scrolling makes the test unstable and not reliable